# AS3 addchild to a movieclip which keeps the motion of the animation

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am really new to flash and AS3 so I do not even know how to ask this question properly.

I have a character (MovieClip) which has an animation, what I want to do is add an item to this character, for example in the "head" layer, and this item should follow the "head" layer.
Thus means the item should be slightly above head in each frame, and the head is constantly changing its position.

What I've got so far is a static item (never moves with the head layer), adding it with "addchildat" to my movieclip.

```
var running : anim_running = new anim_running (); // running movieclip
var cono : i_1  = new i_1 (); // cone head item
running.addChildAt (cono, 10); // adding the cone to the proper layer
cono.x = 20; 
cono.y = -20; // positioning the cone on top of the head
```

with this piece of code this is what it looks like (I can not post images yet)

http://oi45.tinypic.com/2qx6bls.jpg  - this is a frame where the cone is properly positioned
http://oi47.tinypic.com/34g6bub.jpg - but in the next frame the cone won't follow the head layer

Sorry if this is a really noob question. I searched all over google before asking.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to do this (with not too much tricky code), would be to create a "container" movieclip inside the head movieclip where you can add in new hat movieclips.

Then just add the hat to the container. Make sure you have your instance names set up so you can reference them in code. Here is an example:

```
running.head.hatContainer.addChild(cono);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I'm understanding this correctly you'd want to add a container movie clip that has both the head and the cone inside of it. Then you'll animate the container as opposed to the head. That way you can add items to the container relative to the other items as if it were static and the animation keeps playing.

Rough example:

```
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(container);
container.addChild(head);
container.addChild(cone);

TweenLite.to(container, 3, {x:container.x + 50}); /*head and cone move relative to each other because their parent is being animated */
```